# Play audio local file with html

Tags: html, audio, audio-player, local-files

I'm trying to do something like [this](https://simontabor.com/labs/audio/).

But I don't know why I'm not getting this thing work.
Here it is the codepen [example](http://codepen.io/tomasfrancisco/pen/YWxmZG):

```
$('input').on('change', function(e) {

  var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('audio source').attr('src', e.target.result);
  }   

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

The source tag is receiving the base64 mp3 file, but it doesn't load the file into browser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You set the `src` attr directly on the audio element. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vu4vrLo2/1/)

```js
var $audio = $('#myAudio');
$('input').on('change', function(e) {
  var target = e.currentTarget;
  var file = target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  
  console.log($audio[0]);
   if (target.files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $audio.attr('src', e.target.result);
            $audio.play();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
<audio controls id="myAudio" autoplay></audio>
```

Comment: That works!! How is it possible? Every source that I've checked describe that the src file should be on source tag inside audio tag, not in audio.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to make the input allow multiple files and so create a playlist instead of one file at a time?

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio controls>
<source src="yoraudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="youraudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

For more help visit

[This is the simplest way to play audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In UWP you can play a file directly that you can get by name from the Music Library as shown below.  Just get permission to access the Music Library by checking the library in the "Capabilities" tag of your project properties.

```
picksinglefile();
        var l = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary;
        var f = localStorage.getItem("alarmname").toString();
        l.getFileAsync(f).then(function (file) {
            // storagefile file is available
            var s = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);  // its a storage file, so create URL
            player1.setAttribute("src", s);
            player1.play(); // if autoplay is false or off
        });


function picksinglefile() {
// Create the picker object and set options
var fop = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
fop.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.musicLibrary;
fop.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".mp3", ".wav"]);
fop.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {
    if (file) {
        localStorage.setItem("alarmname", file.name.toString());
    } else {
        alert("Operation Cancelled");
    }
});
```