# Use Blazor to play local audio file in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, matblazor

Disclaimer: I am familiar with web technologies but still a newbie.

**Scenario**: I want user to choose an audio file from local file system. Then I wish to show a small audio control on the webpage to play the selection and send the audio back to the server (after clicking a button).

**Problem:** Using MatBlazor [FileUpload](https://www.matblazor.com/FileUpload), I am able to get a stream to the local audio file, but I am at a loss on how to use it with the html `audio` element. **Specifically, how can I pass on the audio stream to `src` in the element?**

One clear way to do this in javascript is to use `<input type="file"/>` element and then use the `Filereader()` to play the audio. Something like this shown here: [Using Filereader.readAsDataURL()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266479/4078182), [Using URL.createObjectURL()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18083202/4078182)

How can I do this in Blazor, ie play local audio file in browser using stream, the right way?

**Current Workaround**: For now, I am reading the stream and converting the audio to base64 string and then passing it on to `audio` element.

The downside of this approach is that for a large audio file of about 18 MB the conversion time is ~30 seconds, and the UI is stuck till then. If I use the javascript way with Interops, then the load time is almost instantaneous, but then I have to use the `input` element and not the `MatFileUpload` component. Another reason to have local file stream is because I want to send this audio file to server for further processing and have found it could be done easily using streams.

The code I am using to convert the audio stream to base64 string:

```cs
async Task FilesReadyForContent(IMatFileUploadEntry[] files)
    {
        string base64Audio; // variable defined outside the function to update DOM
        bool loadingAudio; // defined outside
        try
        {
            file = files.FirstOrDefault();
            if (file == null)
            {
                base64Audio = "Error! Could not load file";
            }
            else
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    loadingAudio = true;
                    await InvokeAsync(() => this.StateHasChanged());

                    await file.WriteToStreamAsync(ms);
                    base64Audio = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

                    loadingAudio = false;
                    await InvokeAsync(() => this.StateHasChanged());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base64Audio = $"Error! Exception:\r\n{ex.Message}\r\n{ex.StackTrace}";
        }
        finally
        {
            await InvokeAsync(() => { this.StateHasChanged(); });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are comparing using the built in `<audio>` element which the browser will stream on demand naturally vs. literally getting the entire file into the browser memory first and then feeding that data into the element.  That is never going to be as performant.  Why do you want to avoid using interop -- interop should not be the first choice, but it's not uncommon for it to be the best choice.  Also, "I want to send this audio file to server for further processing" -- do you want to play what the server provides, or _also_ send it to the server?

Comment: Agreed that interop isn't a first choice. Currently planning to use interop to invoke `URL.createObjectURL()` to load the audio. Yes, want to also send the audio to server. Looking into how I can do that in a way that's robust enough and can handle relatively large file sizes too (~30 MB). If I can achieve both using interop, then won't want to go through the stream route (which yes, will load the audio in memory).